# linux FIFO block on read

Tags: linux, fifo, netcat, mkfifo

I'm doing exercise net0 on https://exploit-exercises.com/protostar/. The content of the exercise is to send requested number as a little endian 32bit int to the server. I came up with the following command lines.

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe  
cat /tmp/pipe | netcat 127.0.0.1 2999 |tee -a /tmp/log | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | xargs -I{} python -c "import struct; print struct.pack('I',int({}))" > /tmp/pipe
```

The second command line doesn't finish, and I found `cat /tmp/pipe` blocking on read (not on open) when use `strace` to debug.

Comment: Have you written something to the pipe?

Comment: @aLeX yes,  the /tmp/log is not empty

Comment: @aLeX and test comamnd line `echo "Please send '220419784' as a little endian 32bit int" | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | xargs -I{} python -c "import struct; print struct.pack('I',int({}))" ` outputs the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason. when the output is not terminal, `cut` will buffer the output. python `print` also needs to be flushed.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226675/194577